# IE11 compatibility mode: jQuery datepicker

Tags: jquery, html, datepicker, internet-explorer-11

I have to update legacy code to works with Microsoft Server 2012 and IE11. This document has an filter feature using jQuery datepicker. To avoid to many changes we agreed to use compatibility mode and IE Developer Tools shows "IE 7 (Default)" for whole page.

When someone clicks on calendar input we see calendar form, but clicking on day is not firing any action. Console is empty.

What we find is that adding "about:blank" to list of sites ("compatibility mode") is solving this issue, but I want to do that the way end user do not have to change anything but adding server link to this list.

what do you think about that issue? Do you know what's the reason of this weird behaviour?

main page html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

datepicker:

```
$( 'input[type=text]#tbDateFrom, input[type=text]#tbDateTo' ).datepicker(
            {
                changeMonth:true,
                changeYear:true,
                showOn:'both',
                buttonImage:'/resources/images/infra/date.png',
                buttonImageOnly:false,
                buttonText:'Select a date',
                showOtherMonths:true,
                selectOtherMonths:true,
                constrainInput:true,
                dateFormat:'mm/dd/yy',
                onClose: function( dateText, inst ){ dateChanged(); },
                onOpen: function(){ $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop:'0px' }, 1500); }
            });
```

jQuery 1.6.2

jQuery UI 1.8.16

Another hint, when I did a click on calendar field it fired link action and link has chaned to "link# as in  ano td onclick wasn't fired.
When I manually invoked DP_jQuery_1421938192356.datepicker._selectDay('#ajdi',0,2015, this) with changed this to object handler it works fine.
So the problem is how IE creates action structure?

```
<TD onclick="DP_jQuery_1421938192356.datepicker._selectDay('#ajdi',0,2015, this);return false;" class=" " sizcache="1519" sizset="0">

<A class=ui-state-default href="http://localhost/dfworks/IMBPalletBrowserController?pl=locPalletMaintenanceFirst&amp;rdmstr=1421937671593#">9</A>

</TD>
```

Comment: @ketan: is that enough? should I add sth more?

Comment: imagine if you were to see this question, what do you do? You skip over it. Try to simplify and isolate the problem, preferably to a single statement. Make the information a bit more structured and perhaps you can tell us if there are any errors in your development tools console?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do with IE compatibility mode ? If your app does not work with it, it does not mean it is your fault... If you understand me. Test it under real stock versions of IE you want to support and that's it. Maybe I didn't get anything of what you are asking though...

Answer (score 0):

Solution was to change version of datepicker from 1.8.16 to 1.11.2.
In new version click event handling was changed to dynamic.